# Cannot convert char to an item in classlibrary in c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, foreach

Completely new to coding and thought I had a good chunk down before this issue. I want to save a new record to sql but trying to capture the id of a chosen item from another table. Thought I could use the same foreach structure I did when I was capturing a list of data, but this is of a single record in a combobox. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Public Usermodel createnewlogin(Usermodel model)
{
    Using(IdataConnection connections = new System.data.Sqlclient.SqlConnection(
        GlobalConfig.cnnstring(db))
    {
        var x = new DynamicParameters();
        x.Add("@name1", model.user1);
        x.Add("@name2", model.user2);

        foreach(Profession p in model.professionid)
        {
            x = new DynamicParameters();
            x.Add("@name1", model.user1);
            x.Add("@name2", model.user2);
            x.Add("@professionid", p.id);

            Connection.Execute("dbo.madeup_insert", x, 
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

The foreach gives the following error: "Cannot convert type 'char' to classlibrary.Profession"

professionid is of type int. It is the incremented id that idenifies the Profession class as a whole in the Usermodel class. When the user selects this value, they are selecting the ProfessionName from the Profession class, which is a type string. So I am trying to save the id associated with that string  from one class, in another based on the ProfessionName chosen in the combobox drop-down. The user never sees and would not know the id qt any point, which is why they select the ProfessionName, not the id itself.

Comment: Of what type is `model` and how is that type defined? It looks like the `professionid` property is some kind of collection of `char`.

Comment: Sorry I think I needed to include the whole thing.

Comment: While you're at it, make sure your code will actually compile. It looks like it was auto-capitalized in Word. It doesn't look like C# code.

Comment: I updated it  and yea it just keeps auto capitalizing everything I am on my phone. But everything is properly cased in visual studio.

Comment: Stack Overflow works better if you copy the actual code from the editor and paste it into the question. You and those who would help you can be certain that your problem is not due to some mistake in transcription.

Comment: So `model.professionid` is a collection of `Profession` objects? The name indicates that it's not, but it may be a bad name.

Comment: The exception indicates that it's a collection of `char`, which the `foreach` enumerates via `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<char>`, and then tries to cast to `Profession`, ...the same way that `foreach` worked before generics were introduced in .NET 2.0.

Comment: model.professionid is.       public int professionid{get; set;} within the Usermodel class, which is the.       public  int id {get; set;} in the Profession class. I'm trying to pull the id from one class to another. Otherwise, a user seletects the ProfessionName from the combobox, I want to save the id of that selection, not the name

Comment: Be sure to [edit] the class definition into your question. Future readers shouldn't have to look through the comments to find all relevant information about your question.

Comment: If `professionid` is `int`, I don't see how you would get that exception. I would expect to see a compiler error like *"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'"*

Comment: Thanks for all your help thus far. New to these forums. I edited the above, and now am more confused if I am getting an error I otherwise shouldn't. It's literally the only thing throughout my entire program that is throwing an error. And that is what the error says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line of code:

```
foreach(Profession p in model.professionid)
```

model.prefessionid is an object of type char.  Under that code you are adding the paramter p.id.  I'm assuming that is the chosen item id you are looking for?  You need to determine what list of data the chosen id is from.  You said that the value you are looking for is supposed to be a single record in a combobox.  So then, instead of the model.professionid you should grab the SelectedValue property or the Text value of the combobox after the user has made their selection.  You will not need a foreach statement for this.

I will need a little more in-depth explanation or code to help you get the desired outcome you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! Ok so the user selects the ProfessionName from a combobox which came from a list of professions in the Profession class. That is then used to connect the rest of the data the user enters to satisfy the Usermodel class. But I don't want the ProfessionName to save to this table in the database, I want the whole record which is indicated by the id where that ProfessionName came from.

Comment: So, you are wanting the `professionid` then, correct?  So, it sounds like the `ProfessionName` is the `DisplayMember` of your combobox (this is the value that is displayed in the combobox when you run the application).  What you should be wanting is the combobox's `SelectedValue` (when you bind your list to the combobox you should have a `DisplayMember` and a `ValueMember`).  You should set the `ProfessionId` as the `ValueMember` for the combobox.  Can you show me the code where you populate the combobox data?  Also, can you show the classes for the `UserModel` and `Profession` model?

Comment: What you are saying is exactly what I have going on right now. Your solution looked like it would work but I am obviously not contructing it properly since I now get an error which says it is having trouble converting nvarchar to int....which is telling me I am still not pulling that id. Ill post the code in another  comment below

Comment: private List<Professions>currentProfessions=GlobalConfig.Connections.GetProfessions_All();   ///   private void ListWireup(){ProfessionValue.Datasource = currentProfessions; ProfessionValue.DisplayMember="ProfessionName"; ProfessionValue.ValueMember="id"; }   ///    public class Professions{public int id{get; set;} public string ProfessionName{get; set;} public string ProfessionLevel{get; set;} public string ProfessionComp{get; set;}}    ///     public class UserModel{ public int id {get; set;} public string ProfessionName{get; set;} public string Username {get; set;} public int SAP{get; set;}

Comment: Thank you for the extra info.  Based on your UserModel class you have here it appears that there is an inconsistency with that model definition and the code in your question.  You have a `model` variable that is supposed to be of type `UserModel` but there is a line that has `model.user1` and there is no property in the UserModel class called "user1".  Can you explain this a little?  And you have the correct property listed as the ValueMember for the combobox, so when you do the insert statement you should just be able to do `ProfessionValue.SelectedValue` ProfessionValue being the combobox

Comment: Sorry I ran out of space and didn't realize I copied the old model. It's.     public class UserModel {public int id {get; set;} public string User1 {get; set;} public string User2 {get; set;} public string ProfessionName {get; set;} public List<ResourceModel> {get; set;} = new List<ResourceModel>();}

Comment: Ok so did what you said and that absolutely worked thank you! But I had to do model.Profession = (int)ProfessionValue.SelectedValue;      and then change the ProfessionName to int in the class. Is that basically how it is to be done or did I just find a complicated way to do what you said? I have to do this a few more times on different forms so wanted to be sure.

Comment: Nope!  That sounds right.  And yes, I forgot you have to cast the SelectedValue as an int because it will be returned as an object.  It sounds like you are squared away.  Would you mind selecting my answer as the answer for the question?  Thanks!

Comment: Just perfect thank you so much for your help. I will do just that.